# Researching Soundcard with RCA Output

Tags: windows-7, sound-card, pci-express

I'm trying to find a sound card for a client who wants one with RCA audio outputs.  Now, while I enjoy good sound, I'm hardly an audiophile, so if anybody has some suggestions for a good low-to-mid-range sound card that installs to a PCIe 1x slot, works with Win 7 and outputs to RCA connections, I'd be much obliged for the assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: The [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) explicitly classifies shopping recommendations as off topic. See also: [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping! « Blog – Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)

Comment: Sorry about that, that's my bad - didn't look closely enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost all modern sound cards have a stereo line out. buy a 5 dollar 1/8" to dual rca adapter at radio shack and charge your client 100 bucks for your trouble. everybody wins!